# From where did Thorin get those Goats?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

In The Battle of The Five Armies movie, we see Thorin lead a shock troop of Fili, Kili and Dwalin to Ravenhill to take out Azog. They ride on huge-horned-rock climbing-goats. Now, I have not read the books but I have come to know that the character of Azog was not there in the books, instead it was Bolg who led the Orcs in the battle for the lonely mountain.

So my question is, where did Thorin get those All Terrain Goats ? Did Dain bring them along with him? are they mentioned in the books or they are just Jacksonian innovation ?

Comment: +1 for "All Terrain Goats".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goats are not in *The Hobbit* by J. R. R. Tolkien, and are entirely an invention of Peter Jackson et al. If the provenance of the AT Goats is unexplained in the film *The Battle of Five Armies* then there is no canon answer.

Comment: pretty disappointing indeed.. :(

Comment: What's the prove they were from Jackson? It was "written by Jackson, Fran Walsh, Philippa Boyens, and Guillermo del Tor"

Answer (score 6):

Dain brings them in the film. Thorin then gets on one when he meets him.

They are not in the book.